# Alt+Tab for switching applications looks like GNOME 2, not like the screenshots I've seen

Tags: shortcut-keys, application-switcher

Switching between applications with <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> works properly but it does not look like the screen shots on the Ubuntu website. Instead it looks similar to what I had with gnome2 in previous versions.

What could be the problem and how can I fix it?

Comment: A screenshot of the problem would prove a bit useful..

Comment: Also, are you using a laptop? If so, which is its GPU? (i.e. nvidia/ati, which model)

Answer (score 1):

If it looks like the image below, you're probably running Unity 2D, which does not yet have the nicer alt+tab that Unity has. If you haven't actively chosen to use Unity 2D, that might mean your video card or graphics driver doesn't support it.

[image]